# Bind a directory as me

Tags: permissions, mount, su, bind

Analogous for a regular user running a thin FTP server (where others can access the file system with his/her permissions), can a regular user (through fuse maybe) "mount" a directory for others to use as him/her?

I tried `bindfs` but this far it does not seem to screen user ids. I want anyone using the mount have the exact same permissions as I do. Just as if I was running a very dumb file server.

Comment: How about `bindfs -p a=rwD --chmod-deny src dst`?

Comment: You could run an sshd, grant access to someone, then have them use sshfs.